# MSAL UserAgentApplication: Local storage not working

Tags: azure-ad-msal

UserAgentApplication.localCache = "localStorage" is not working.

**Steps to reproduce:**

```
var client = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(config.aadClientId, config.aadAuthority...);

client.cacheLocation = "localStorage"; 

client.loginPopup().then( ... );
```

**Result:**
The MSAL tokens are stored in session storage. (Chrome developer tools)

**Expected:**
Tokens should be in local storage.

I am using msal 0.1.1 javascript library via https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/0.1.1/js/msal.min.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround we figured out that instantiating the Msal.Storage singelton before creating the UserAgentApplication, the local storage will be used. This is due to the fact, that when instantiating the UserAgenApplication the Msal.Storage is fixed configured with session storage. Therefore subsequent call of client.cacheLocation = "localStorage" doesn't not work, since the Msal.Storage is already created.

```
 ...
 new Msal.Storage("localStorage");

 var client = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(config.aadClientId, config.aadAuthority, ...);
 ...
```

Comment: Your solution seems to make it use local storage, yay!

The problem I'm facing now is that when creating the Msal.UserAgentApplication it doesn't use the data from the Local Storage to populate the user object. Did you manage to solve this problem? Do you have a code snippet for how to create the Msal.UserAgentApplication with the Local Storage data?

Extremely poor user experience to have to sign in again when refreshing the page.

Thanks!

Comment: since 0.1.2 passing through ctor param like this `var client = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(config.aadClientId, config.aadAuthority, ()=> {/*callback*/}, { cacheLocation: 'localStorage' });` should do the job. Source: [microsoft-authentication-library-for-js#58](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/58#issuecomment-333730346)