# How To Use LocalStorage with MSAL.js

Tags: local-storage, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

How do I use LocalStorage with [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js)?

According to [this](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/docs/classes/_useragentapplication_.msal.useragentapplication.html#cachelocation), there's a property, cacheLocation, I need to set to 'localStorage'.

The following is still using sessionStorage:

```
var clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority, function (errorDesc, token, error, tokenType) {
        // Called after loginRedirect or acquireTokenPopup
    });
clientApplication.cacheLocation = 'localStorage';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the documentation is slightly out of date, see this GitHub issue: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/58.  To set the cache location in the latest releases of msal.js, use the following pattern:

```
var userAgentApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID,
     null, authCallback, { cacheLocation: 'localStorage' }); // to set it to localStorage
```

Comment: That GitHub issue let me to a related SO issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114583/msal-useragentapplication-local-storage-not-working/44133641#44133641