# Login redirect a user with Azure AD B2C from an Angular application and msal.js

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to get an Angular 4 app to correctly do an implicit authentication with Azure AD B2C. I'm using msal.js to try and make it to work. I've checked the very limited [official sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-angular2.4-spa), but it's of no real use as it's using a popup to login and I want to do a redirection.

What I have now is the following authentication service that I'm injecting in my app and that should take care of all the authentication.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Msal from 'msal';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

    private tenantConfig = {
        tenant: "example.onmicrosoft.com",
        clientID: "redacted (guid of the client)",
        signUpSignInPolicy: "b2c_1_signup",
        b2cScopes: ["https://example.onmicrosoft.com/demo/read", "openid"]
    }

    private authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/" + this.tenantConfig.tenant + "/" + this.tenantConfig.signUpSignInPolicy;

    private clientApplication: Msal.UserAgentApplication;

    constructor() {
        this.clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(this.tenantConfig.clientID, this.authority, this.authCallback);
    }

    public login(): void {
        this.clientApplication.loginRedirect(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes);
    }

    public logout(): void {
        this.clientApplication.logout();
    }

    public isOnline(): boolean {
        return this.clientApplication.getUser() != null;
    }

    public getUser(): Msal.User {
        return this.clientApplication.getUser();
    }

    public getAuthenticationToken(): Promise<string> {
        return this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes)
            .then(token => {
                console.log("Got silent access token: ", token);
                return token;
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("Could not silently retrieve token from storage.", error);
                return this.clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes)
                    .then(token => {
                        console.log("Got popup access token: ", token);
                        return token;
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log("Could not retrieve token from popup.", error);
                        this.clientApplication.acquireTokenRedirect(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes);
                        return Promise.resolve("");
                    });
            });
    }

    private authCallback(errorDesc: any, token: any, error: any, tokenType: any) {
        console.log("Callback")

        if (token) {
            console.log("Id token", token);
        }
        else {
            console.log(error + ":" + errorDesc);
        }

        this.getAuthenticationToken();
    }
}
```

But it's not working. I get the ID token correctly, and it's valid, so the "Id token" does receive a value that I can use, but for a limited time.

The issue is when I try to get the authentication token. The first call, to `acquireTokenSilent` returns an error that says : `Token renewal operation failed due to timeout: null`.

Then, I'm getting a popup that asks for a username and password, which, after a while disappears and I get an error that says `User does not have an existing session and request prompt parameter has a value of 'None'.`.

**Edit:**

So, I think I understand what's going on exactly and to reproduce the issue on a sample application that you can get here: https://github.com/Gimly/NetCoreAngularAzureB2CMsal

If you connect from the homepage and then go to the fetchData page (the one with the weather forecast) you can see the auth token be correctly redeemed by `acquireTokenSilent` (open the browser console to get all the logs). But, if you refresh the page directly on fetchData, you can see the same behavior that I described, with `acquireTokenSilent` failing with the error about a timeout.

My best guess would be that, fore some reason, even though `getUser` returns a correct value, msal is not completely initialized before I call `getAuthenticationToken` and it's the reason for it to fail completely.

Now the real question... How do I make sure that it's completely initialized before trying to get the token?

Comment: I wonder what would happen [if you tried localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201872/how-to-use-localstorage-with-msal-js)?

Comment: @spottedmahn just tried, and it's the same behavior.

Comment: @spottedmahn I found a bit more information about the issue, could you check my edits?

Comment: You have typo in your code, clientId Value has single quote which is not closed

Comment: @Maverik thanks, I've edited and corrected the typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so the issue I was facing was caused by two things:

1) a bug in msal.js that caused the initialization process to not be fully completed at the end of the constructor call, and I was calling the `acquireTokenSilent()` before it had fully initialized. This was fixed in the latest version (as of writing, still in the dev branch of the project). [See this GitHub issue for more info](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/150#issuecomment-338061763).

2) I hadn't fixed the redirect URI, which caused the library to take the current URL as redirect URI which would fail because it wasn't in the list of allowed redirect URIs.

After those two issues fixed, the code I posted in my question is working as expected.

Comment: can you source #1?  do you have a github issue you can link it to?

Comment: @spottedmahn Updated the answer with the GitHub issue.

Comment: @Gimly Could you please add your imports into the example, I am trying to follow and example that uses and older version of msal (0.1.1) which references files in an 'out' directory in the auth service. This does not seem to exists anymore so my imports do not work?

Comment: @Magrangs I'm not sure I get what you're asking. You mean the NetCoreAngularAzureB2CMsal sample app? I updated it to use msal 0.1.3 and it should be working correctly.

Comment: @Gimly I followed the link to the sample app and found the updated imports (using * from msal) the older version i was following was here: https://github.com/sunilbandla/msal-angular-sample/blob/master/src/app/services/auth.service.ts which uses some sort of output directory. Might just be worth adding the imports into the AuthenticationService  in the question so we don't have to follow the link maybe?

Comment: Ah ok, yes that was an old version that I didn't really mean to upload that got the things from an "out" library, I was using it before the 0.1.3 of msal was official. Anyway, yes I'll update the question to add the imports.

Comment: @Gimly I just added some edits to make it so it compiles straight away (removed the Msal on Msal.User and removed console.log(Callback'))

Comment: @Gimly p.s. many thanks for your sample, helped a lot. The official documentation is so poor!

Comment: @Magrangs you're welcome, don't hesitate to add issues there if encounter a difficulty. I'm going to write a blog post about it to make it a bit clearer as well. I have proposed adding it to the official msal documentation, they said they'll look into it, but haven't got any feedback yet. Please also upvote the question and answer if you haven't already :).

Comment: Just a quick important point for anyone else reading this. If you are using azure b2c with openid connect, pass [your client id] INSTEAD OF THE SCOPES as the first param into acquireTokenSilent or acquireTokenPopup to get the id token back otherwise you may get issues with scopes. 
 i.e..acquireTokenSilent([environment.clientId])

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/97bc30db201138af4055916f33d868ab6b1f6a8c/src/UserAgentApplication.ts#L843-L847) for MSAL js, you should be able to use acquireTokenRedirect instead of acquireTokenPopup.

Comment: If I have a valid `id_token` why couldn't I call `acquireTokenSilent()`?  I just redirected the user to login, why would I want to redirect them again?

Comment: Well, the acquireTokenRedirect doesn't seem to work much better either. And it creates a double redirect, as @spottedmahn said.

Comment: @parakh I updated my question with more information and a project where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: partially unrealeted but, @parakh I am not able refresh my token, I am using `userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent(b2cScope, 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{{clientDomain}}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignIn', user)` , but I am getting error. I also tried by giving null value to Authority, but still error is coming.