# Chrome extension service workers: use Chrome.Storage as MSAL cache location

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, storage, service-worker, azure-ad-msal

In order to make use of Chrome.Storage in MSAL, it (msal) would need to support setting asynchronous cache location on instantiating the PublicClientApplication class.

Anyone know any way to do this currently?

Answer (score 0):

For chrome extension support for MSAL there is a feature request opened [here](https://github.com.cnpmjs.org/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/3666) . However, you can use the  MSAL MemoryStorage option and implement your own caching outside MSAL until we are able to provide built-in support for async storage interfaces.

For reference on using  LocalStorage with MSAL.js, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201872/how-to-use-localstorage-with-msal-js).

For MSAL-Brower support read more [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/pull/2060).

Thank you