# Unable to use localStorage as cache location in React Native App

Tags: javascript, react-native, local-storage, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am developing a React Native App with expo-cli.  I am using ADFS to authenticate users in the app, and in particular, I am using MSAL.js.  I've got the authentication working on web, however, I cannot get the App to run on iOS or Android.  I am getting the error: "The cache location provided is not valid.  Provided value: localStorage.  Possible values are: localStorage, sessionStorage."

I've tried using sessionStorage instead of localStorage, but I just get the same error, except it tells me the provided value was sessionStorage.

I found a thread where someone was having a similar problem as well, here: [MSAL UserAgentApplication: Local storage not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114583/msal-useragentapplication-local-storage-not-working).  I tried the workaround, but then I get the error: "undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Msal.Storage("localStorage")')".

If I try calling Msal.Storage("localStorage"), it tells me that msal.Storage is not a function.

I've also tried explicitly passing in values to the UserAgentApplication function from my config, rather than passing in the config itself:

```js
var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig.auth.clientId, msalConfig.auth.authority, msalConfig.auth.redirectURI, { cacheLocation: 'localStorage' });
```

Here's the snippet of code where I believe the problem is:

```js
const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "<client-Id>",
        authority: "<authority>",
        redirectURI: "http://localhost:19006"
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true
    }
};

//new Msal.Storage("localStorage");
var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
```

I would expect the call to UserAgentApplication to correctly use the localStorage as cache on both iOS and Android, but this does not seem to be the case.  The app works perfectly in my browser on my laptop, though, without any cache/localStorage hiccups.  Are there any workarounds/fixes for this that do not require Msal.Storage?  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote my own library to do it.  I guess MSAL.js doesn't have the right calls to work with mobile browsers.

https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/azure-ad-graph-expo

The library below does just what I  want, which is log into Azure AD, retrieve a token, and then use that token to query MS graph for the appropriate user data.